# Java array using a while loop

Tags: java, arrays

I have to:

- create this java array;
- loop through it using a while loop;
- terminate the program if the sum adds up to 100;
- and print the sum and the numbers that I did put into the array.

I can't figure out how to do that, here is my code so far, any help would be appreciated.

```
public class december2012 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {  

        int sum=0;            

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);            

        int i=1;

        int [] array = new int[i];

        while( i > array.length || sum <= 100) {

          System.out.println("Write in the " + i + " number") ; 
          array[i]=input.nextInt();
          sum=+array[i];
           System.out.println("sum is " + sum); 

        }            

        }
    }
```

Comment: Customarily, Java classes begin with a capital letter.

Comment: you mean sum = sum + array[i], note that i is 1 all the time, and so you get an ArrayIndexOutOf BoundException.

Answer (score 5):

```
int i = 0;                            // array starts from 0
int [] array = new int[100];          // create larger array
while(i < array.length && sum <= 100) // i should be less then length
                                      // && instead of ||
{
   System.out.println("Write in the " + i + " number") ; 
   array[i] = input.nextInt();
   sum += array[i];                   // += instead of =+
   System.out.println("sum is " + sum);
   i++;                               // increment i 
}
```

[**Ideone DEMO**](http://ideone.com/NRx4LV)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when setting

```
int i=1;
int [] array = new int[i];
```

you are creating an array with 1 slot, which index is `0`. This is crucial to take note of, when you're doing this:

```
array[i]=input.nextInt();
```

because, as you defined it, `i` is not 1, which means that your assign the 2nd index, index `1` to the return value of `input.nextInt()`.

Your while loop is also off, as i should never be bigger than the length of the array. You should use a for-loop instead, in this fasion:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = input.nextInt();
    sum += array[i]

    if (sum > 100) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment the `i` variable; currently its value is always `0`, so you're only setting the first element in the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class December2012 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[100];
        int sum = 0;
        int i = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (sum <= 100 && i < array.length) {
            System.out.print("Write in the " + (i + 1) + "th number: ");
            array[i] = input.nextInt();
            sum += array[i];
            i++;
        }
        System.out.print("You added: ");
        for (Integer i : array) System.out.print(i + " ");
        System.out.println("\nsum is " + sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about like this, simple way of doing:

```
int sum = 0;
while(true) {
   //Do calculations
   if(sum >= 100) {
      break;
   }
}

System.out.println("Sum is : " + sum);
```